# Reset tabindex for initial keyboard navigation *and* scrollIntoView for mouse users

Tags: javascript, html

There are some [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65619627/is-there-a-way-to-reset-to-current-tabindex-position) threads on this topic that didn't asnwer my question.

On the click of a button I need to scroll to a certain section of the form. Also, there is a Skip-Nav link at the top of the page, `skipnav`, that should also receive the first TAB focus in this case, just for keyboard navigation. It shouldn't be auto-focused, but if a keyboard user presses TAB, tabbing should begin from that `skipnav` element.

The following code doesn't work:

```
    // Focus/blur "skipnav" to prepare initial TAB-ing for keyboard users, AND scroll to section for mouse users
    document.getElementById('skipnav')?.focus();
    document.getElementById('skipnav')?.blur();
    var stepIndicatorElement = document.getElementsByClassName("usa-step-indicator")[0];
    if (stepIndicatorElement) {
        stepIndicatorElement.scrollIntoView();
    }
```

The problems are:

- The first `focus()/blur()` pair by itself, with no other code, will focus the **next** element **after** `skipNav` when you press TAB for the first time;
- The `scrollIntoView()`, while not focusing anything right away, does something with the tab order such that pressing TAB will focus the first element in that section. Even if I have the `focus()/blur()` above, pressing TAB will still focus something **in that section**. Does `scrollIntoView` reset or prepare a new tab order in some way, even without focusing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out both of these questions.

- `scrollIntoView` is described as an "[experimental feature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51958275/1005607)" and it does affect Tab Order. The safe way to scroll to an element without affecting Tab Order is with `getClientBoundingRect()` and `window.scrollTo`:

  ```
   var stepIndicatorElement = document.getElementsByClassName("usa-step-indicator")[0];
   if (stepIndicatorElement) {
       var y = stepIndicatorElement.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.scrollY - 15; // e.g. with extra offset
       window.scrollTo(0, y);
   }
  ```
- To manually set the current tab index on the very first tabbable element, create a pseudo-tabbable element (`tabindex="-1"`) right before it. This means that the user **can't** get to it with a TAB, **but** you can programmatically focus it with `focus()` (and then `blur()`).  On the next press of a TAB, the desired "first" element will be focused. That pseudo-tabbable element can be the containing DIV, e.g.:

  ```
  <div id="header" tabIndex={-1}> {/* tabindex=-1 makes an element programmatically focusable but not TAB-focusable from the user's perspective */}
       <a id="skipnav" className="skipnav" href="#main-content">Skip to main content</a>
  </div>
  ```

then from JS:

```
    document.getElementById('header')?.focus();
    document.getElementById('header')?.blur();
```